# Can 'come up to' be used in the context of a bill?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is the use of *come up to* correct in this context?

> We bought tons of stuff at X place. The whole bill **came up to X dollars**.

I often see people (non natives) use *come out* in this situation:

> The whole set up **came out to be** Y dollars.

Which of these two or both is correct idiomatic usage in this context?

Comment: I think the 'be' in the first example you gave is implied (and therefore correct).

Comment: I think it's more likely that non-native speakers would say, "The whole thing turned out to be Y dollars." (I'm not sure what you meant by "set up"; probably *setup*; though its meaning would be more like some sort of operation than raw materials.)

Comment: This will vary a lot depending on where the speaker is from, how old they are, their educational background, etc. I personally prefer *came to* for these examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

> The whole bill **came up** to X dollars.

because on a bill you are adding up indiviual charges that add *up* to the total amount.

You could also say:

> The whole bill **amounts/amounted** to X dollars.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would just say "came to *X* dollars":

> **come to**
> ( *preposition* ) to amount to (a sum of money): *your bill comes to four pounds* ([dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/come+to?s=t))

*Come/came up to* is not exactly wrong, but it isn't a commonly use phrase for talking about money in the way that *come/came to* is.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are acceptable, though they have slightly different meanings.

**Came up to** emphasizes the rising total, which eventually stopped rising when it reached X dollars.

**Came out to be** expresses initial uncertainty about the bill, followed by the revelation that X dollars was the result.

Comment: I think *came out at* is more idiomatic than *came out to be*. Not absolutely sure, though.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I've never heard "came out at" in regular North American English usage.